# gevent pool.wait_available() method meaning

Tags: python, gevent, eventlet, greenlets

Look, people. We have a question about gevent.pool class and pool.wait_available() method, both code snippets

**1.**

```
def fetch(url):
    print 'start fetching...', url
    data = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    print url,':',data.code

urls = ['http://www.google.ru', 'http://www.s-str.ru', 'http://www.vk.com', 'http://www.yandex.ru', 'http://www.xxx.com']

pool = Pool(2)

def producer():
    for url in urls:
        pool.spawn(fetch, url)
    pool.join()

p = gevent.spawn(producer)
p.join()
```

**2.**

```
def fetch(url):
    print 'start fetching...', url
    data = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    print url,':',data.code

urls = ['http://www.google.ru', 'http://www.s-str.ru', 'http://www.vk.com', 'http://www.yandex.ru', 'http://www.xxx.com']

pool = Pool(2)

def producer():
    for url in urls:
        pool.wait_available()
        pool.spawn(fetch, url)
    pool.join()

p = gevent.spawn(producer)
p.join()
```

give us similar results:

```
start fetching... http://www.google.ru
start fetching... http://www.s-str.ru
http://www.google.ru : 200
start fetching... http://www.vk.com
http://www.s-str.ru : 200
start fetching... http://www.yandex.ru
http://www.yandex.ru : 200
start fetching... http://www.xxx.com
http://www.vk.com : 200
http://www.xxx.com : 200
```

Can anyone explain the meaning of wait_available() method? And possible cases of it's usage.

=======update========
I already monkey pathched it, it works correctly, all I want to know - is the difference between theese two code snippets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working with `gevent` you need to patch standard module before.

```
>>> import gevent.monkey
>>> gevent.monkey.patch_all()
>>> ...
>>> p = gevent.spawn(producer)
>>> p.join()
start fetching... http://www.google.ru
start fetching... http://www.s-str.ru
http://www.google.ru : 200
start fetching... http://www.vk.com
http://www.vk.com : 200
start fetching... http://www.yandex.ru
http://www.yandex.ru : 200
start fetching... http://www.xxx.com
http://www.xxx.com : 200
http://www.s-str.ru : 200
```

You can see, that `pool.wait_available()` works predictable.

**Update**

`Pool` works the same way only for `spawn` function (it will wait for available "slot" in pool). If you need to provide other functionality based on `Pool` state (logging, tracing, monitoring) - you definitely will use functions like `wait_available`, `free_count` etc. If you only need to `spawn` new green thread - you can rely on `Pool` implementation.

Comment: The question is - for what do i need this method, if standard behavior  of pool is similar, why call it directly? I want to understand the difference between the standart pool behavior and the way it goes with directly calling this method. o_O

Comment: Thx for the answer, i understand now. Is there any other docs for gevent, except official site? For example docs on the page http://www.gevent.org/gevent.pool.html doesn't contain explanation of some methods.(wait_available() and etc)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know any good source of `gevent` documentation, except own experience :)

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**: `wait_available` isn't necessary if you're using spawn as the same check is run in both methods. However, if you're using `apply_async` and want to not submit threads above the cap of the pool, then you should call `wait_available` first.

---

For maybe a slightly more clear explanation.. There's a few ways to achieve the same thing with gevent's `Pool` class. Using `spawn` on the pool will block until there's a space available in the `Pool` to run a new greenlet. Here's a quick example:

```
import gevent.monkey
gevent.monkey.patch_all()
import gevent.pool
import time

def my_slow_function():
    time.sleep(5)

def log(text):
    print '%d : %s' % (int(time.time()), text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    thread_pool = gevent.pool.Pool(5)
    for i in xrange(20):
        log('Submitting slow func %d' % i)
        thread_pool.spawn(my_slow_function)
    thread_pool.join()
    log('Exiting')
```

The output of this shows that it will spawn these in groups of 5, since the pool contains space for 5 greenlets:

> 1403037287 : Submitting slow func 0
>   1403037287 : Submitting slow func 1
>   1403037287 : Submitting slow func 2
>   1403037287 : Submitting slow func 3
>   1403037287 : Submitting slow func 4
>   1403037292 : Submitting slow func 5
>   1403037292 : Submitting slow func 6
>   1403037292 : Submitting slow func 7
>   1403037292 : Submitting slow func 8
>   1403037292 : Submitting slow func 9
>   1403037297 : Submitting slow func 10
>   1403037297 : Submitting slow func 11
>   1403037297 : Submitting slow func 12
>   1403037297 : Submitting slow func 13
>   1403037297 : Submitting slow func 14
>   1403037302 : Submitting slow func 15
>   1403037302 : Submitting slow func 16
>   1403037302 : Submitting slow func 17
>   1403037302 : Submitting slow func 18
>   1403037302 : Submitting slow func 19
>   1403037307 : Exiting

As you can see they are spawned in groups of 5 roughly 5 seconds apart. If you dig into the gevent code and look at the Pool object, you can see that calling `spawn` will ask for a lock in the `Pool`s internal semaphore that's used to track running greenlets.

Conversely, if you try this same code using `apply_async` instead of `spawn`, it will force all the calls to run at the same time:

> 1403037313 : Submitting slow func 0
>   1403037313 : Submitting slow func 1
>   1403037313 : Submitting slow func 2
>   1403037313 : Submitting slow func 3
>   1403037313 : Submitting slow func 4
>   1403037313 : Submitting slow func 5
>   1403037313 : Submitting slow func 6
>   1403037313 : Submitting slow func 7
>   1403037313 : Submitting slow func 8
>   1403037313 : Submitting slow func 9
>   1403037313 : Submitting slow func 10
>   1403037313 : Submitting slow func 11
>   1403037313 : Submitting slow func 12
>   1403037313 : Submitting slow func 13
>   1403037313 : Submitting slow func 14
>   1403037313 : Submitting slow func 15
>   1403037313 : Submitting slow func 16
>   1403037313 : Submitting slow func 17
>   1403037313 : Submitting slow func 18
>   1403037313 : Submitting slow func 19
>   1403037318 : Exiting

You can see here that there's no blocking or waiting, they're all shoved in at the same time. However, if you throw in a `wait_available()` at the beginning of the for loop, you go back to having a similar behavior to `spawn`.

> 1403038292 : Submitting slow func 0
>   1403038292 : Submitting slow func 1
>   1403038292 : Submitting slow func 2
>   1403038292 : Submitting slow func 3
>   1403038292 : Submitting slow func 4
>   1403038297 : Submitting slow func 5
>   1403038297 : Submitting slow func 6
>   1403038297 : Submitting slow func 7
>   1403038297 : Submitting slow func 8
>   1403038297 : Submitting slow func 9
>   1403038302 : Submitting slow func 10
>   1403038302 : Submitting slow func 11
>   1403038302 : Submitting slow func 12
>   1403038302 : Submitting slow func 13
>   1403038302 : Submitting slow func 14
>   1403038307 : Submitting slow func 15
>   1403038307 : Submitting slow func 16
>   1403038307 : Submitting slow func 17
>   1403038307 : Submitting slow func 18
>   1403038307 : Submitting slow func 19
>   1403038312 : Exiting

Once again, looking at the source in gevent, `wait_available` does the same check that happens as a result of calling `spawn`, which is checking the semaphore to see if there's actually room in the pool.